# Good IDE for Elixir

Tags: ide, elixir

I am looking for an IDE that does atleast some of the following

- Code completion when typing variable names and possible
  functions after pressing `.`
- Show a functions signature and docs
- Navigate to the function/variable/module's definition

It would be nice if it could also

- Warn about errors
- Code generation
- Scaffold basic projects

Comment: This question would probably be more relevant on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ than on Stack Overflow.

Comment: good question! sorry but none of them is not right except that vim and emacs. gonna try ide(rust, elixir) on my own editor(read).

Answer (score 44):

There is a great Elixir extension support for **[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)** and there are currently 2 extensions to add the language to the tool, my preference being [vscode-elixir](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/mjmcloug.vscode-elixir). You can add it by hitting ctrl+P then typing "ext install vscode-elixir".

This extension adds rich elixir language support to VS Code including:

- Syntax Coloring
- Snippets
- Intellisense

[image]

There is also a sublime integration called **[ElixirSublime](https://github.com/vishnevskiy/ElixirSublime)**. It has most of the same features. However, it hasn't been updated in many years.

Comment: be careful with ElixirSublime : the PackageControl version is outdated and has some issues (at least it had for me). You may want to install it from github directly, or to look at that thread for troubleshooting https://github.com/vishnevskiy/ElixirSublime/issues/6

Comment: I couldn't get it to work fully even if I installed it from github and looked through the issues for possible solutions.

Comment: @nietaki are you referring to elixir sublime or elixir for vscode?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't specific: ElixirSublime

Comment: It's 2018 and elixir for sublime package seem to have been abandoned. No code updates for the past 2 years.

Comment: Now it's 2020 : latest commit 7781388 on Dec 25, 2016.

Answer (score 29):

The Alchemist Elixir Tooling integration Emacs package brings the following functionality so far:

- Mix integration
- Compile & Execution of Elixir code
- Inline code evaluation
- Inline macro expanding
- Documentation lookup
- Definition lookup
- Powerful IEx integration
- Smart code completion
- Elixir project management
- [Phoenix](http://www.phoenixframework.org/) support
- Integration with [company-mode](http://company-mode.github.io/)

More infos available here: https://github.com/tonini/alchemist.el/blob/master/README.md

If you have questions you can find me on IRC channel **#elixir** and **#emacs-elixir** (nickname: **tonini**)

Answer (score 26):

[Atom](https://atom.io/) with [atom-elixir](https://github.com/msaraiva/atom-elixir). An excerpt from the current features (on top of the default Atom goodness, all working out of the box):

- Autocomplete
- Go to definition
- Go to Documentation View
- Quoted Code view
- Expand Macro view
- All features depending on aliases and imports are already supporting the new v1.2 notation.

[image: atom-elixir autocomplete]

I'm personally using it together with the [vim-mode plugin](https://github.com/atom/vim-mode) and it seems like there's no conflicts.

I'm usually an IntelliJ person, but the IntelliJ plugin is still lacking in some of the autocomplete functionality that I'm used to.

Edit: after working with Atom and elixir for about 5 months now I wrote a [blog post](https://nietaki.github.io/2016/11/14/atom-as-an-elixir-ide/) summarising how I tweaked it to work for me and referencing my entire config.

Comment: Hi, how does this compare to [language-elixir](https://github.com/elixir-lang/language-elixir)?

Comment: I didn't really compare the two, but if I understand correctly, it actually builds on top of language-elixir - it uses syntax highlighting from it and adds everything else.

Comment: Atom is now my default editor

Comment: One thing that I wasn't aware until recently that it works nicely with https://atom.io/packages/symbols-view - `⌘+R` lets you search through the symbols/functions in the current file and jump to their definition.

Answer (score 16):

I have tried all of well known text editors and corresponding elixir packages.

- **IntelliJ with plugin** : No alchemist server integration so it is worse then others. Also IntelliJ is slower to start than other IDE-s and editors.
- **Visual Studio Code** : Missing some shortcuts but generally you can Elixir code in this editor if you are already using it for other languages.
- **Sublime Text** : Same as VS code, if you are using sublime now than you can use it for Elixir
- **Atom** : Very good support for everything except code format (beautify) but that will be fixed soon.
- **Emacs** : Best support and package but it is not for the feint of heart if you do not use emacs already.

So if you do not have hard preference for some of this editors choose between **Emacs** or **Atom** to code Elixir in.

Comment: Saša, your review is missing VIM. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 11):

If you are a vim user, There is [alchemist.vim](https://github.com/slashmili/alchemist.vim) plugin which has

- Completion for Modules and functions
- Documentation lookup for Modules and functions
- Jump to the definition
- Mix integration
- IEx integration

Answer (score 6):

Atom has a great package for elixir and mostly any other language, you should go and give it a try.

Comment: While this answer is very unconvincing and lacking in details, [atom-elixir](https://github.com/msaraiva/atom-elixir) works out of the box and works well, including autocompletion.

Answer (score 6):

Now, there's also an Elixir plugin for IntelliJ: https://github.com/KronicDeth/intellij-elixir

The author also did a talk at ElixirConf 2015: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=0Its8r5RBf0

Comment: Seems like it has come a long way since last time I heard about it. Thanks for the update. Have you tried it yourself, what do you use currently? Asking because I use IntelliJ and Jetbrain software at work, while I use Atom for Elixir at home. The switch should be simple, but IntelliJ feels so resource hungry compared to Atom.

Comment: I just saw the talk. I myself use Vim for almost anything.

Comment: I'm using Atom with plugin, but it doesn't work very well, because of recent Atom updates.

Comment: @PatrickOscity you can use the IDEAVim plugin in JetBrain IDEs to get vim keybindings in their IDEs.

Comment: @LukeImhoff thanks but the reason I'm invested in Vim is because I hope to never switch editors again. I've seen IDEs come and go for 10 years now, Vim on the other hand feels like it will still be around in two decades and is still under active development. Besides, I don't think IDEAVim can emulate Vim closely enough that I might like it; even the highly praised evil mode for emacs didn't convince me.

Answer (score 4):

If you are from Java background then don't expect IDE like eclipse or IntelliJ. Though IntelliJ works fine with Elixir, but as of now, I was not able to make it work with Phoenix framework. Your best bet is **[Atom](https://atom.io/)**, or [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) if you are a guru. **[VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com)** is another cool tool very similar to Atom.

Comment: As of v7.4.0 (released 2018-03-07) IntelliJ Elixir has support for parsing/higlighting EEx templates and breakpoint debugging in EEx templates, which no other IDE/Editor plugin has at this time.

Answer (score 3):

I'll add that [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) and [Alchemist](https://github.com/tonini/alchemist.el) are a powerful combo for writing Elixir code.  But I doubt there's anything available anywhere that has all the features you list above.

Answer (score 3):

**Visual Studio Code** with **[vscode-elixir](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mjmcloug.vscode-elixir)** extension.

This extension adds rich elixir language support to VS Code including:

- Syntax Coloring
- Snippets
- Intellisense

Answer (score 2):

[image] 
elixir-tmbundle is great and highly lightweight package available for Sublime text support of Elixir Lang, you can simply add it to sublime text by simply running.

```
cd ~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages # If you are on Linux using sublime text-2

cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 2/Packages # If you are on OS X

cd %HOMEPATH%\AppData\Roaming\Sublime^ Text^ 2\Packages # If you are on Windows Vista or above

cd %HOMEPATH%\Application^ Data\Sublime^ Text^ 2\Packages # If you are on Windows XP

git clone git://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir-tmbundle Elixir
```

There is TextMate support for this package as well, you can follow this link for more info.

https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir-tmbundle

Comment: Is this for sublime 2 only?

Comment: No, I am using it with sublime text as well, I mentioned the version for the shake of example only.